# Would a Vulkan program run on a device without gpu (discrete or integrated)?

Tags: vulkan

Perhaps this question could be rephrased as 'what would happen if I were to try and run a Vulkan program on a cpu-only build'.

I'm wondering whether the program would run but not produce output, crash or not build in the first place (although I expect the building process to be for a cpu architecture instead of a gpu architecture).

Would it use the on-motherboard graphics to produce output? In that case, what would happen if the program was run on a cpu-only server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how the program initialized vulkan.

Any build can have the vulkan loader installed this is the dynamically loaded library that finds the actual driver, if that is missing the program would be unable to load the loader and may either fail to start or show an error message, depending on how they try and load that.

If no device is available then the number of devices is 0. This is again up to the application to manage. Either by going for an alternative graphics API (opengl) or a error message and failing to start.

Comment: Actually, usually the instance creation fails with `VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER` before you even can get devices.